# Is it possible to pass value to include layout without create variable only by xml?

Tags: android-databinding

Android Studio 3.1, Java 1.8.
I use data binding from Google.

Here my **profile.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="handler"
            type="com.myproject.ui.ProfileActivity" />
    </data>


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/common_color_bg">


        <include
            android:id="@+id/prfoileToolbar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:title="@{@string/profile}" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Here **tool_bar.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="title"
            type="String" />

    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolBarConstraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolBar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/tool_bar_height"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbaTitleTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@{title}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toolBar"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/toolBar"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/toolBar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/toolBar" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

And here my activity:

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ProfileBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.profile);
        binding.setHandler(this);
    }

}
```

And it's work fine. In included xml (**tool_bar**) success show text "**Profile**". Nice.

I do this by create variabel "**title**" in **tool_bar.xml**

The question is:
Is it possible to pass string value to tool_bar.xml and set it to "**toolbaTitleTextView**" without create variable "**title**" ONLY by xml?

Comment: Are you looking for additional functionality or a different way of doing things? Data binding was designed to work as in your example. Are you trying to do something like `<include toolbaTitleTextView.title="@{@string/profile}" .../>`? If so, that's not possible. You need a variable in order to pass values into the include.